# In Postfix, is it possible to reject email from a specific sender to a specific recipient?

Tags: postfix

I have an alias forwarding email to a limited number of recipients. It's a private alias that we wish to reserve for certain communications.

**Q1**: a member of the public now knows the alias. Is it possible to block one specific email address from being able to send email to the alias concerned. Of course, a blocking rule,could easily be bypassed by the rogue sender using a different email address but we can address that on a case by case basis.

**Q2**: a better alternative would be to restrict use of the alias to only those email addresses that are members of that alias. For example:

```
abc: def, ghi, jkl, mno
```

Emails to alias abc@ can only be sent by addresses: def, ghi, jkl, mno

Achievable?

Comment: Here are [some ideas from the Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html#internal).

Comment: Looking forward to seeing what you came up with.

Comment: I just implemented what you suggested - many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the advice on the [link](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html#internal) that [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) provided which is based on the sender SMTP envelope address, and therefore is subject to SMTP sender spoofing.

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    ...
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/protected_destinations
    ...the usual stuff...

smtpd_restriction_classes = insiders_only
insiders_only = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/insiders, reject

/etc/postfix/protected_destinations:
all@my.domain   insiders_only
all@my.hostname insiders_only

/etc/postfix/insiders:
my.domain       OK  matches my.domain and subdomains
another.domain  OK  matches another.domain and subdomains
```